# How to get CppUnit light running?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I'm new to C++ and to unit testing of c++. I tried to get CppUnit light running, without success so far and I actually have no idea what to do now. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "CppUnitLite/TestHarness.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TestResult tr;
    TestRegistry::runAllTests(tr);

    return 0;
}


TEST( Stack, creation )
{
    CHECK_EQUAL("a", "a");
}
```

In Codeblocks I got the following error messages:

> UnitTestTest/main.cpp|10|undefined reference to TestResult::TestResult()|
>   UnitTestTest/CppUnitLite/Test.h|21|undefined reference to SimpleString::~SimpleString()|
>   UnitTestTest/main.cpp|17|undefined reference to Test::Test(SimpleString const&)|

Comment: add -lcppunit to Linker.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to include 2 dirs for include

```
project_dir (as it use include CppUnitLite/x.h)
project_dir/CppUnitLite (all header files including Simple Strings)
link to -lCppUnitLite
```

CppUnitLite has nothing to do with cppunit, the tag is wrong
I added 3 Cmake files tested working

```
[gliang@www CppUnitLite]$ cat ../CppUnitLite/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
enable_testing()
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CppUnitLite
)
link_directories(
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

for test dir

```
[gliang@www CppUnitLite]$ cat ../CppUnitLite/test/CMakeLists.txt
set(test_SRCS
Stack.h
StackMain.cpp
StackTest.cpp
)
add_executable(cppunitLite ${test_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(cppunitLite CppUnitLite)
add_test(NAME cppunitLite COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/cppunitLite)
```

for src(lib) dir

```
[gliang@www CppUnitLite]$ cat ../CppUnitLite/src/CMakeLists.txt
set(lib_SRCS
Failure.cpp
SimpleString.cpp
Test.cpp
TestRegistry.cpp
TestResult.cpp
)
add_library(CppUnitLite ${lib_SRCS})
```

The original project is not active for months
 https://github.com/smikes/CppUnitLite

Please conside other alternatives